# Giving action listeners string qualities and using those strings in an if statement

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe

As a sort of side project to teach myself action listeners, buttons, and Jframes I started a bit of a profiler based on TV shows and the like. The buttons and actionlisteners work but I just can't figure out how to give the action listeners strings and call on those strings. Where am I going wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class ProfileCreatorWithoutRecords extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
final String dramaAnswer;
final String comedyStyleAnswer;
final String comedyShowAnswer;

final JFrame fridayFrame = new JFrame();
fridayFrame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://s21.postimg.org/xfdlwcr2f/friday_night_lights_season_4_pictures.jpg"));
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 500, 350, this);
    }
});
final JButton fridayButton = new JButton("Friday Night Lights");
fridayFrame.add(fridayButton);
fridayFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
fridayFrame.setSize(500, 350);
fridayFrame.setVisible(true);
fridayFrame.setLocation(0, 0);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////MAD MEN
final JFrame madFrame = new JFrame();
madFrame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://s27.postimg.org/c1lxi135v/mad_men_1024x768.jpg"));
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 1024, 768, this);
    }
});

final JButton madButton = new JButton("Mad Men");
madFrame.add(madButton);
madFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
madFrame.setSize(1024, 768);
madFrame.setVisible(true);
madFrame.setLocation(900,0);

////////////////////////////////////////HOUSE OF CARDS 
final JFrame houseFrame = new JFrame();
houseFrame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://cdn.bgr.com/2013/04/netflix-house-of-cards.jpg"));
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 620, 458, this);
    }
});
final JButton houseButton = new JButton("House of Cards");
houseFrame.setVisible(true);
houseFrame.setSize(620, 458);
houseFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
houseFrame.add(houseButton);
houseFrame.setLocation(0, 400);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////GAFFIGAN 
final JFrame gaffiganFrame = new JFrame();
gaffiganFrame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://thepost.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Jim-Gaffigan-Wilbur-Artist1.jpg"));
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 550, 253, this);
    }
});
final JButton gaffiganButton = new JButton("Clean comedy");
gaffiganFrame.setVisible(false);
gaffiganFrame.setSize(550, 253);
gaffiganFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
gaffiganFrame.add(gaffiganButton);
gaffiganFrame.setLocation(0, 0);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////LOUIE
final JFrame louieFrame = new JFrame();
louieFrame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://static.dudeiwantthat.com/omg/video-clips/Louis-CK-Live-at-the-Beacon-Theater-1604.jpg"));
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 504, 420, this);
    }
});
final JButton louieButton = new JButton("Dirty, rant comedy");
louieFrame.setVisible(false);
louieFrame.setSize(504, 420);
louieFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
louieFrame.add(louieButton);
louieFrame.setLocation(500, 0);

final JFrame officeFrame = new JFrame();
officeFrame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://sarahsayswatchit.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/the-office.jpg"));
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 600, 600, this);
    }
});
final JButton officeButton = new JButton("The Office");
officeFrame.setVisible(false);
officeFrame.setSize(600, 600);
officeFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
officeFrame.add(officeButton);
officeFrame.setLocation(0, 0);

final JFrame southFrame = new JFrame();
southFrame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://2.images.southparkstudios.com/default/image.jpg?quality=0.8"));
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 480, 360, this);
    }
});
final JButton southButton = new JButton("South Park");
southFrame.setVisible(false);
southFrame.setSize(480, 360);
southFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
southFrame.add(southButton);
southFrame.setLocation(650, 0);

final JFrame bigbangFrame = new JFrame();
bigbangFrame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-w8v5FzJwAdk/U_NlRh73i5I/AAAAAAAABsU/02yuF3IPs78/s1600/the-big-bang-theory%3DSatanismo.png"));
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 1000, 562, this);
    }
});
final JButton bigbangButton = new JButton("Big Boob Blonde Lady");
bigbangFrame.setVisible(false);
bigbangFrame.setSize(1000, 562);
bigbangFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
bigbangFrame.add(bigbangButton);
bigbangFrame.setLocation(0, 800);

fridayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent fridayclicked) {
        String dramaAnswer = "fridaynightlights";
        fridayFrame.setVisible(false);
        madFrame.setVisible(false);
        houseFrame.setVisible(false);
        gaffiganFrame.setVisible(true);
        louieFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
});

madButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent madclicked) {
        dramaAnswer = "madmen";
        madFrame.setVisible(false);
        fridayFrame.setVisible(false);
        houseFrame.setVisible(false);
        gaffiganFrame.setVisible(true);
        louieFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
});

houseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent houseclicked) {
        dramaAnswer = "houseofcards";
        fridayFrame.setVisible(false);
        houseFrame.setVisible(false);
        madFrame.setVisible(false);
        louieFrame.setVisible(true);
        gaffiganFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

});

gaffiganButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent cleanpicked) {
        comedyStyleAnswer = "CleanComedy";
        louieFrame.setVisible(false);
        gaffiganFrame.setVisible(false);
        officeFrame.setVisible(true);
        southFrame.setVisible(true);
        bigbangFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

});
louieButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent dirtypicked) {
        comedyStyleAnswer = "DirtyComedy";
        louieFrame.setVisible(false);
        gaffiganFrame.setVisible(false);
        officeFrame.setVisible(true);
        southFrame.setVisible(true);
        bigbangFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
officeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent officepicked) {
        comedyShowAnswer = "Office";
        officeFrame.setVisible(false);
        southFrame.setVisible(false);
        bigbangFrame.setVisible(false);
    }

});
southButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent southpark) {
        comedyShowAnswer = "southpark";
        officeFrame.setVisible(false);
        southFrame.setVisible(false);
        bigbangFrame.setVisible(false);
    }

});
bigbangButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent bigbang) {
        comedyShowAnswer = "bigbang";
        officeFrame.setVisible(false);
        southFrame.setVisible(false);
        bigbangFrame.setVisible(false);
    }
});
}

giveReccomendation(dramaAnswer, comedyStyleAnswer, comedyShowAnswer);
}

public static void giveReccomendation (String dramaAnswer, String comedyStyleAnswer, String comedyShowAnswer) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("public static void started");
    JFrame personFrame = new JFrame();
    personFrame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://images.vcpost.com/data/images/full/29158/person-of-interest-on-cbs.jpg"));
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 1000, 650, this);
        }
    });
    JLabel personLabel = new JLabel("Person Of Interest");
    personFrame.add(personLabel);
    personFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    personFrame.setSize(1000, 650);
    personFrame.setVisible(false);
    personFrame.setLocation(0, 0);
    System.out.println("person frame created");

    if (dramaAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("fridaynightlights")
            && comedyStyleAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("clean")
            && comedyShowAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("office")) {   
        personFrame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("person frame set visible");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: cutting it down to a minimal example would probably make it easier to find the issue

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please explain "...how to give the action listeners strings and call on those strings"

Answer (score 1):

Because you are placing your only call to giveRecommendation in your main thread, what you are doing is calling the method giveRecommendation after your frame and all of your listeners are set up.

While your action listeners will correctly in setting the value of your local Strings, they will perform no other actions.

Therefore if you want to call the giveRecommendation method, place it in one of your existing action listeners, or create a new button and action listener.

Answer (score 1):

Creating multiples frames and then only showing one is not a very good design.

Maybe you can use:

1. a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), or.
2. a `JTabbedPane`.

> I just can't figure out how to give the action listeners strings and call on those strings.

Not sure if I understand the question, but a JButton has a `setActionCommand(...)` method. This String can be accessed in the `ActionEvent` using the `getActionCommand()` method of the `ActionEvent`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information and working examples.